# rewriting htaccess file loosing css files broblem

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi this is my first question here thank you for your help.

in my website ( using php ) i have a page  called  `http://domaine.com/details.php?slug=this-is-a-slug` and i want it to looks like this   `http://domaine.com/this-is-a-slug` and in the same page `details.php` i have system comments with pagination so sometimes the URL might looks like this  `http://domaine.com/details.php?slug=this-is-a-slug&page=2` if the user click on the next page to see comments  .

in the root i have :

```
 .htaccess file
index.php
 details.php
style.css
images/..
js/
css/details.css and other stylelsheet files
details.php 
.
.
. others pages and files
```

so i wrote this  code bellow in .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ details.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule  ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$  details.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

and the url become indeed `http://domaine.com/this-is-a-slug` but when i click on pagination  and the url become  `http://www.domain.com/this-is-a-slug/2/` .

the pagination works but the problem is that  the css files not loading and my website looks weird ?

can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your CSS is using a relative file path URI like `styles.css` rather than an absolute (relative to web directory) URI like `/styles.css`.

What happens is that when your URI gets an apparent added "directory level" by adding the pagination parameter like this `/this-is-a-slug/2/`, the browser would interpret a relative path reference to your CSS file as:

```
/this-is-a-slug/styles.css
```

Of course this file does not exits there and you will get 404 error and n CSS on page.

You can look on your browser's web development network tab to verify that you are getting this 404.

For example, you could change an external CSS reference like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```

Or, for images, change something like this:

```
<img src="some_image.jpg">
```

to this:

```
<img src="/some_image.jpg">
```

Comment: so   do you have any solution i can put in .htaccess ?

Comment: If this is truly the problem, a rewrite is not your solution, you simply need to refer to the CSS file in it's correct location.

Comment: do you mean evry css file and every image location ? i hope there is .htaccess solution !

Comment: @JirayaZiane You could redirect static asset requests, but that it just going to add a hacky complexity to serving your static assets files that just doesn't need to be there. Relative paths should typically be avoided anyway unless you have a very specific intended use case to have an HTML page and its asset references tightly coupled like this.  You should get in the habit of thinking of your static assets as something separate from your application from a application routing perspective. This may be one time pain to make your application better and a good lesson learned for you.

Comment: thank you for your time i'am a just a novice.  can you explain your comment with more simplystic . sorry , do you mean do i have to put pages  in folders ? just tel me what to do !

Comment: @JirayaZiane I added some additional examples.